# How do I locate specific file in a post that affects ssl?

Tags: plugins, ssl

I recently migrated my old website to this domain: https://thequintessentialmind.com/

It is a wordpress site and in the articles, example here: https://thequintessentialmind.com/how-to-never-run-out-of-things-to-say/, in the console of google inspector it suggest that there is a .gif file that should be renamed from http to https.

[image]

I have difficulty locating that part of the code in any of the php files. Any ideas where could it be or which plugin is generating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick squint at your site reveals that you're serving it with Nginx, so a simple `.htaccess` redirect won't work.

The following block in your Nginx config should take care of any stray locally-served files that are still coming over http:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

If you were running Apache, the following in your `.htaccess` before the WordPress section would achieve the same thing:

```
# HTTP to HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The above is presented in lieu of tracking down the specific file, as the page no longer seems to be throwing the mixed content error.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. It actually does but only on chrome. Not sure why this still happens.

Comment: Doesn't in my Chrome, which seems to suggest that the culprit is a plugin or userscript.

Comment: You are right. I rebooted my laptop, cleared cache and it stopped showing.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried clicking on the filename generating the error? Usually you will see the file/resource in the sources tab of your browser inspector.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/142402)

Comment: @cjbj Oh, somehow it does provide an answer. Actually a pretty practical one. If it is *the* answer? We will see :)

Comment: Wasn't the question to locate the source? Not resolve how resources are served?

Comment: sorry, but have to agree the answer is useless as an answer (would have been a good comment). not everything loaded is a file, or it might be dynamically generated url which is just impossible to "search for" without first have some deeper understanding of how the code works

Comment: The question was: How do I locate specific file in a post that affects ssl? The answer is: By changing your server configuration to load all resources over https. Got it.